# How to use like in sql for selecting exact matching characters among multiple match in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-like

I want to fetch exact matching characters among multiple match in a string in sql .

table 1 - keyword column
1)test 3)newtest

table 2 - string column
1)there should be sometestfor
2)and foronenewtestkey

output - when search test it should show sometestfor  only and not show and foronenewtestkey because
newtest is a different keyword

I am using stringcolumn LIKE '%[^a-z]'+keywordcolumn+'[^a-z]%'

but not getting results

Comment: I think that you may want to look at the `REGEXP` syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html  Hard to know which database you are targetting as it is tagged with mysql and sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below operation to get your work done.

```
StringColumn LIKE "%test%" AND StringColumn NOT LIKE "%newtest%
```

Thanks, Santosh